# ¿Cópmo solucionar TypeError: string indices must be integers?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el resultado de una unión con merge de dataframes.

```
actor_crew = pd.merge(actor, crew, on='directors', how='inner')
basic_actor_crew = pd.merge(Title_Data, actor_crew, on='tconst', how='inner')
basic_actor_crew_ratings = pd.merge(basic_actor_crew, ratings, on='tconst', how='inner')
basic_actor_crew_ratings.head()

tconst  primaryTitle    originalTitle   genres  primaryName     primaryProfession   averageRating   numVotes    primaryName_size    primaryProfession_size

tt4283088   Battle of the Bastards  Battle of the Bastards  Action,Adventure,Drama  Miguel Sapochnik    [director, art_department, producer]    9.879267    154016  16  3
```

Y en esta función es donde me salta el error.

```
def get_director(x):
for i in x:
    if i['job'] == 'Director':
        return i['name']
return np.nan

**basic_actor_crew_ratings['director'] = basic_actor_crew_ratings['primaryProfession'].apply(get_director)**
basic_actor_crew_ratings['primaryProfession'] = basic_actor_crew_ratings['primaryProfession'].apply(lambda x: x[:3] if len(x) >=3 else x)
basic_actor_crew_ratings['primaryProfession'] = basic_actor_crew_ratings['primaryProfession'].apply(lambda x: [str.lower(i.replace(" ", "")) for i in x])
```

Y me tira este error

```
117 def get_director(x):
118     for i in x:
--> 119         if i['job'] == 'Director':
120             return i['name']
121     return np.nan
```

Cuando le comento el código, funciona.

Alguna sugerencia de donde partir para la solución?

Comment: ¿De dónde salen   `i['job'] ` e  `i[name]`?¿La columna `primaryProfession` que tipo de dato contiene? Aparentemente es una lista de cadenas , en ese caso debería ser  `def get_director(x): if 'Director' in x...` pero ten en cuenta que estás usando `apply` sobre la columna `primaryProfession` y por tanto  el argumento `x` que recibe `get_director` es una lista (`[director, art_department, producer]` ).

Comment: i['job'] e i[name], lo cambie por i[primaryProfession] e i[primaryName] porque no correspondian al dataframe. Haciendo basic_actor_crew_ratings['primaryProfession'].dtypes me retorna que es un objecto. basic_actor_crew_ratings['primaryProfession'] creo que es un pandas series.

Comment: Ok, para saber que es exactamente lo que contiene la columna puedes hacer `print(type(df['primaryProfession'][0]))` o `print(type(x))` dentro de `get_director` si quieres ver que está recibiendo la función.